# glDrawArrays segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to render a simple triangle with OpenGL 3.3, but when I call glDrawArrays my program crashes with a segmentation fault. The language I'm using is C++ and I use the libraries SDL, glew and glm.
I think what happens is, that the draw call tries to access data that doesn't belong to the vertex buffer I have set up.
For reasons that don't really matter I can not provide the whole source code of my program. However I can provide some relevant snippets and a trace of the OpenGL calls issued, generated with the tool Apitrace.

```
[...]

glClearColor(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
glClear(mask = COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

glGenVertexArrays(n = 1, arrays = &1)
glBindVertexArray(array = 1)
glGenBuffers(n = 1, buffer = &1)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 1)
glBufferData(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size = 72, data = blob(72), usage = GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glVertexAttribPointer(index = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = GL_FALSE, stride = 24, pointer = NULL)
glVertexAttribPointer(index = 1, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = GL_FALSE, stride = 24, pointer = 0xc)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)

glCreateShader(type = GL_VERTEX_SHADER) = 1
glShaderSource(shader = 1, count = 1, string = &"#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 iPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 iNormal;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(iPosition.x, iPosition.y, iPosition.z, iNormal.z * -1.0);
}", length = NULL)
glCreateShader(type = GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) = 2
glShaderSource(shader = 2, count = 1, string = &"#version 330

out vec4 oFragColor;

void main() {
  oFragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}", length = NULL)
glCompileShader(shader = 1)
glGetShaderiv(shader = 1, pname = GL_COMPILE_STATUS, params = &1)
glCompileShader(shader = 2)
glGetShaderiv(shader = 2, pname = GL_COMPILE_STATUS, params = &1)
glCreateProgram() = 3
glAttachShader(program = 3, shader = 1)
glAttachShader(program = 3, shader = 2)
glBindAttribLocation(program = 3, index = 1, name = "iNormal")
glBindAttribLocation(program = 3, index = 0, name = "iPosition")
glLinkProgram(program = 3)
glGetProgramiv(program = 3, pname = GL_LINK_STATUS, params = &1)
glGetAttribLocation(program = 3, name = "iPosition") = 0
glGetAttribLocation(program = 3, name = "iNormal") = 1

glGetIntegerv(pname = GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, params = &0)
glUseProgram(program = 3)
glBindVertexArray(array = 1)
glClear(mask = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLES, first = 0, count = 3) //incomplete (segfault here)
```

As I said, I think the problem is, that the draw call tries to access data in a wrong way. I have already checked the data in the vertex buffer using glGetBufferSubData. So here is the Code i use to set up the VAO:

```
Mesh::Mesh(const std::vector<Triangle>& triangles): _vao(0), _vbo(0) {
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
  glBindVertexArray(_vao);

  glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);

  struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 normal;
  }

  Vertex* vertecies = new Vertex[triangles.size() * 3];

  // [...]
  // Convert triangles to vertecies, store them in the array.

  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.size() * 3 * sizeof(Vertex), vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  delete[] vertecies;

  //Position
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
  //Normal
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<void*>(3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

I suspect the error to be in the way I call glVertexAttribPointer.
If other parts of the program are necessary to answer, leave me a comment and I'll see what I can do to provide them.

Comment: First of all, you bind different locations of attributes in shader and `glBindAttribLocation` calls. (Shader: `iPosition = 0`, `iNormal = 1`, glBindAttribLocation: `iNormal = 0`, `iPosition = 1`).

Comment: That was actually just a mistake I've made while copying the trace.
In fact, I never even call glBindAttribLocation myself. It seems to be the way OpenGL handles the (location = 0) in the shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see anything wrong with your code. I usually get this problem when my context isnt set correctly. For example, when I dont have GLEW set up correctly in my case. That may be the same problem for you.

Comment: That got me on the right track. I forgot to call SDL_INIT(), which kept an error from getting thrown when creating the OpenGL Context.  The error got thrown because I wasn't using the nvidia drivers, even though I installed them. In the end I had to add my user to the video group to make them work (dammit suse, why isn't such an important step documented in the offical wiki?). Still no triangle on my screen, but I'm sure I can figure that out. At least the program doesn't segfault anymore.